# Getting the values of multiple checkboxes and displaying in a separate input text field

Tags: jquery, forms

```
        <input type="checkbox" id="bulb1" name="bulb" value="1" />
        <label for="bulb1" class="fontawesome-lightbulb"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bulb2" name="bulb" value="1" />
        <label for="bulb2" class="fontawesome-lightbulb"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bulb3" name="bulb" value="1" />
        <label for="bulb3" class="fontawesome-lightbulb"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bulb4" name="bulb" value="1" />
        <label for="bulb4" class="fontawesome-lightbulb"></label>
```

Idea is to display a binary value if the bulbs are clicked.

```
    if (jQuery('input#bulb1').is(':checked')) { var1=1; } else { var1=0 };

    if (jQuery('input#bulb2').is(':checked')) { var2=1; } else { var2=0 };
    if (jQuery('input#bulb3').is(':checked')) { var3=1; } else { var3=0 };
    if (jQuery('input#bulb4').is(':checked')) { var4=1; } else { var4=0 };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A_Manojkumar/s9gJX/

Is there a good approach for this?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve in fiddle?

Comment: When a bulb is clicked, the value 1 is pushed into the input field #binary. If not, 0 should be retained. Similarly for all the bulbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `length` property;

```
var var1 = jQuery('input#bulb1:checked').length;
var var2 = jQuery('input#bulb2:checked').length;
var var3 = jQuery('input#bulb3:checked').length;
var var4 = jQuery('input#bulb4:checked').length;
```

### EDIT

*When a bulb is clicked, the value 1 is pushed into the input field #binary. If not, 0 should be retained. Similarly for all the bulbs*

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    var var1 = $('input#bulb1:checked').length.toString(10);
    var var2 = $('input#bulb2:checked').length.toString(10);
    var var3 = $('input#bulb3:checked').length.toString(10);
    var var4 = $('input#bulb4:checked').length.toString(10);
    $('#binary').val(var1 + var2 + var3 + var4);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VLL43/1/)

Comment: Thanks Satpal. How do I push these values into the #binary input form? Since it will be for conversion. Commas between them won't help.

Comment: @user2532458, I have updated answer see is this you want